# How to create a class library (c#) in visual studio code using .net 4.7 version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, class-library

I am trying to create a class library from visual studio code, as i cannot use visual studio because of some organizational limits.

So when i tried to create the class library i was able to use the c# dev kit,.Net install extensions from the visual studio code. But these are asking me to download .net sdk 8.

I am developing this class library to make it fit in to an automation process which accepts earlier versions of .Net (4.7,4.8) etc.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can help you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-8-0

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command on your terminal

`dotnet new classlib -n YourLibraryName -f net48`

Comment: this got failed, but i tried with the netstandard2.0 which works. 
Thank you for the help @hasanUtebay